# Accessing dict value inside a list inside a list

Tags: python

Here is a subset of data of a JSON file extracted from Major League Baseball:

```
  "liveData": {
    "plays": {
      "allPlays": [
        {
          "runners": [
            {
              "details": {
                "event": "Single",
                "runner": {
                  "id": 656941,
                  "fullName": "Kyle Schwarber",
                },
                "responsiblePitcher": null,
                "isScoringEvent": false,
                "rbi": false,
                "earned": false,
                "teamUnearned": false,
                "playIndex": 6
              }
            }
          ]
```

I have failed at accessing the id value so I can include it in a dataFrame being built.

I began by using `json_normalize` on the JSON file.

After successfully extracting other values I get to this:

```
data=[]
plays = j['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']
    for play in plays:
      x = play['runners']['details']
```

I get the message that 'details' is not an acceptable index since it is a string and not an integer or a slice.

How do I get that inner value of 'id' ?

Comment: `"runners"`' value is a *list* - note the `[` just after it at the end of the line - , so it would be `x = play['runners'][0]['details']`.

Comment: Since there are potentially many runners,, you might want a nested `for` loop right after you existing one that does `for runner in play['runners']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = json.loads(json_data)

id_value = data["liveData"]["plays"]["allPlays"][0]["runners"][0]["details"]["runner"]["id"]

print("ID:", id_value)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for the good details. You gave me just what I needed